# display list of friend user is not showing all users

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that retrieve list of friends from the MySQL table using the friend_array field.

But the problem is that the browser doesn't show more than one picture, but it shows the default one.

## this is the code

```
   <?php 
//***********************Displaying Friend List*************************//
$friendList = "";
$friendListTitle="";
if($friend_array!="")
{
    $friendArray = explode(",", $friend_array);

    $friendArray = array_slice($friendArray,0,6);
    $friendCount = count($friendArray); 
    $friendListTitle = '<div class="title"> '.$username.'\'s Friends('.$friendCount.')</div>';
        //iterating to retrieve what it's needed as values
/*$frnd1 = $friendArray[0];
$frnd2 = $friendArray[1];
/*$frnd3 = $friendArray[2];
$frnd4 = $friendArray[3];
$friendList .='<div style="background-color:"#CCC";>'.$frnd1.'<br />'.$frnd2.'</div>';*/

        $i=0;
        $friendList ='<div  style="background-color:"#CCC"; >'; 
        foreach($friendArray as $key => $value)
        {
            $i++;
            $check_pic = "members/$value/image01.jpg";
            if(file_exists($check_pic))
            {
                $frnd_pic = '<a href="profile.php?user_id='.$value.'"><img src = \"$check_pic\" width = "52px" border = "1"/></a>';
            }
            else
            {
                $frnd_pic = '<a href="profile.php?user_id='.$value.'"><img src = "members/0/image01.jpg" width = "52px" border = "1"/></a>&nbsp;';
            }
            $sqlName = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM members WHERE user_id= '$value'LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
            if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlName,MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                $fname = $row['first_name'];
                $lname = $row['last_name'];
                $friendList = '<div title="'.$fname.' '.$lname.'">'.$frnd_pic.'</div>';
            }
        }
        $friendList.='</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you images and divs that contain the records of friends is being replaced by next record so it display the last record of your friends.
try this may help you

```
$friendList = "";
$friendListTitle="";
if($friend_array!="")
 {
   $friendArray = explode(",", $friend_array);

   $friendArray = array_slice($friendArray,0,6);
   $friendCount = count($friendArray); 
   var_dump($friendCount);
   $friendListTitle = '<div class="title"> '.$username.'\'s Friends('.$friendCount.')</div>';
    //iterating to retrieve what it's needed as values
    $i=0;
    $friendList ='<div  style="background-color:"#CCC"; >'; 
    foreach($friendArray as $frndlist => $value)
    {
        $i++;
        $check_pic = 'members/'.$value.'/image01.jpg';
        if(file_exists($check_pic))
        {
            //storing each friend images separately
            $frnd_pic[$i] = '<a href="profile.php?user_id='.$value.'"><img src = "'.$check_pic.'" width = "52px" border = "1"/></a>';
        }
        else
        {
            $frnd_pic[$i] = '<a href="profile.php?user_id='.$value.'"><img src = "members/0/image01.jpg" width = "52px" border = "1"/></a>&nbsp;';
        }
        $sqlName = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM members WHERE user_id= '$value'LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlName, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $fname = $row['first_name'];
            $lname = $row['last_name'];
            $friendList .= '<div title="'.$fname.' '.$lname.'">'.$frnd_pic[$i].'</div>';
        }
    }
    $friendList.='</div>';
```

}

Comment: still the same nothing it change

Comment: yes all the images are named image01  but the default image has a path members/0/image01.jpg  else if the user have an image the path members/'.$value.'/image01.jpg

Comment: noo the problemm that it show just one and picture and it is the default one

Comment: after i did var_dump($i)  the browser display int1  int 2

Comment: please echo one more time these variables checkpic ,fname,lname

Comment: it show first name last name default pic for one user but this one have a pic and the other do not show a pic but it must display a default image

Comment: my friend you have to go line by line where the data are missing ,i can't do this from here .(although when you see the page source in browser is image tag for there for another record ?).