# i have a list of friends that i want to be displayed in the profile page using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, css

i have a list of friends that i want to be displayed in the profile page using php and mysql

but the problem is that it show the list vertical but what i want is to display each three on a row not each pic in a row

## this is the code

```
<?php 
//***********************Displaying Friend List*************************//
$friendListTitle = "";
$friendList = "";
if($friend_array!="")
{
    $friendArray = explode(",", $friend_array);

    $friendArray = array_slice($friendArray,0,6);
    $friendCount = count($friendArray); 
    $friendListTitle = '<div class="title"> '.$username.'\'s Friends('.$friendCount.')</div>';
        //iterating to retrieve what it's needed as values
        $i=0;
        $friendList .='<div  style="background-color:"#CCC"; >'; 
        foreach($friendArray as $frndlist => $value)
        {
            $i++;
            $check_pic = 'members/'.$value.'/image01.jpg';
            if(file_exists($check_pic))
            {
                $frnd_pic = '<a href="profile.php?user_id='.$value.'"><img src = "'.$check_pic.'" width = "52px" border = "1"/></a>';
            }
            else
            {
                $frnd_pic = '<a href="profile.php?user_id='.$value.'"><img src = "members/0/image01.jpg" width = "52px" border = "1"/></a>&nbsp;';
            }
            $sqlName = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM members WHERE user_id= '$value'LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlName))
            {
                $fname = $row['first_name'];
                $lname = $row['last_name'];
                $friendList .= '<div title="'.$fname.' '.$lname.'">'.$frnd_pic.'</div>';
            }
        }
        $friendList.='</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: for($i=0,$i<3;$i++){do something here}

Comment: If your question is about layouts/alignments then you should tag it under HTML/CSS

Comment: you are not talking about php and Mysql, your issue is CSS and html

Comment: An duplicate of this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602315/display-list-of-friend-user-is-not-showing-all-users
same code again ...

Comment: @ jcho360 @ php NoOb i know that is a html and css but within php as you see

Answer (score 0):

Try making div to be displayed as inline-block, becouse by default DIV tag is displayed as block which takes a whole row of space and prevents others to be placed there ;)
`$friendList .= '<div title="'.$fname.' '.$lname.'" style="display:inline-block;">'.$frnd_pic.'</div>';`

Comment: thank you Benas Radzevicius for you r help as soon as i could i will upvote you